# Is a Galois category small?

Tags: category-theory, galois-theory

I think a Galois category is necessarily small, otherwise a lot of constructions run into trouble (e.g. the subcategory of connected objects may not be a set, hence we don't have a projective system of minimal pairs). It is clear in the case of covering spaces and field extensions, I wonder if it can be proved directly from the axioms (e.g. one set of axioms can be found [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck%27s+Galois+theory)).

P.S. By 'small' I mean it is equivalent to a small category.

Comment: It seems to me there are no size restrictions in the axioms. If you permit yourself one Grothendieck universe you could consider the covering spaces of a space with a universe- sized fundamental group, or something like that.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for your comment. Just to confirm: when we prove the fundamental functor is pro-representable, we need the Galois category to be small right? I couldn't find any reference explicitly addressing this issue.

Comment: If you want your inverse system to be small then you should assume the Galois category is small, or at least that the fibre functor is generated by a small set in a suitable sense. I am not familiar with the classical theory.